# Discord Bot not recognizing command names

Tags: python, discord, command, bots

This is what I wrote just to start my discord bot, but whenever I try using the command ?hi, I get the error message

> Ignoring exception in command None:
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "hi" is not found"

I've tried a couple things but I am new at this and nothing is working.

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands, tasks 
import os 
import random 

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '?')

@client.command
async def hi(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Hello World")
```

the answer below helped for this problem, here is my new code as the bot now doesn't give an error message, but doesn't respond to commands

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands 
import os 
import random 

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

client.run('Token')

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '?')

@client.command 
async def hi(ctx): 
  await ctx.send("Hello World")
```

Comment: never created a bot before but don't you need something like `@client.command(name='hi')` before your function?

Comment: well @depperm I tried that and it is now recognizing the command and I am getting a new error message that I understand even less

Comment: what is the new error message?

Comment: @depperm I did keep messing with it maybe you can help I cannot figure out if this will work but the New, New error message is an indentation one and I don't know what I'm doing wrong ```@client.command
async def hi(ctx):
  @client.command(name=hi(ctx))
 await ctx.send("Hello World")```

Comment: please edit your question or ask a new one. Indentation is important for python. It doesn't look like you did the exact line I commented above.

Comment: Oh I thought that would work, my formatting was right until I sent the comment, I'm not sure why but now I've fixed the first problem now I just have another one which Im attempting to tackle

Comment: have you tried my first comment?

Comment: where did you think I should put it I tried after the client.command line and it did not change anything and I tried just replacing the client.command line and that also didn't change anything

Comment: I believe it should replace what is currently there, `@client.command` and `client.run(...)` should be last. Based off this [tutorial](https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/#using-bot-commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a discord bot, you need an authentication token provided by discord. I see your a using discord.py for your Bot. They have explanations on [how to create a bot account](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/discord.html)

As for the code of your bot, you first need to create a bot Client and then run it, like here

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


client.run('your token here')
```

Don't forget to add your token when running the bot

After all you've put that in place, then you can use the discord.ext module to make the commands like you did. (Your code works, it's just missing the whole discord bot part shown above)

ext stands for extension, if you don't even have the main module (discord), then it's not going to do anything

> Take not that **discord** and **discord.ext** are 2 different modules, so you need to import both

Comment: I did that and now once I run it says i've logged in as my bot (Thank You) and I type in the command and now I don't get an error but my bot doesn't send anything back when I type in ?hi

Comment: @RandomDuck can you update the question with your current code?

Comment: @depperm sure one sec, Done

Comment: @RandomDuck it's client.command() and not client.command
The parenthesis are important here. Also make sure that the client.run() is at the end of the program